# valueWithNonretainedObject not working in iPhone 6 & 6 plus

Tags: objective-c, swift

#### Class A

```
 func addObjectToFieldsOfInterest(title:String,bgColor:UIColor)
    {
        let contactKey = NSValue(nonretainedObject: title)
       self.classBObj.addContact(title, withName: title, withStyle: styleObj, andSelectedStyle: styleObj, andContactKey: contactKey.description)
    }
```

#### Class B

```
    - (void)addContact:(id)contact withName:(NSString *)name withStyle:(THContactViewStyle *)bubbleStyle andSelectedStyle:(THContactViewStyle *)selectedStyle andContactKey:(id)contactKey
    {
        //id contactKey = [NSValue valueWithNonretainedObject:contact];
        if ([self.contactKeys containsObject:contactKey]){
            NSLog(@"Cannot add the same object twice to ContactPickerView");
            return;
        }

// Main functionality goes here
    }
```

- Class A - Swift Class
- Class B - Objective C

Calling the Class B method from Class A works fine when I run on iPhone 4s & 5.

But it prints `"Cannot add the same object twice to ContactPickerView"` log when run on iPhone 6 & 6+. Why?

Comment: Where are you calling `addObjectToFieldsOfInterest` from?

Comment: from viewWillAppear() method

Comment: I am facing same problem. How did you solve this ?